# On click, all divs are removed, instead of one

Tags: jquery

I have several div's called 'albumbox'. For each the unique element is in 'data'.
I want to remove the one I just clicked and confirmed in the confirmBox. But after cancelling one, and confirming another albumbox, all previous (cancelled) albumboxes get deleted as well.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
$('.albumbox').live('click',function(){  
    var boxID = $(this).attr('data');

    $(".confirmBox").show();
    $("#abort").live('click',function(){  $(".confirmBox").hide(); });
    $("#confirm").live('click',function(){ 
        $(".confirmBox").hide();
        $('[data^=' + boxID + ']').slideUp('3000');
    });
});
```

Comment: _"Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?"_ You're using `live`...

Comment: If it gets deleted, you have a serious problem, as it should either just be hidden or slide up, but maybe live() now actually deletes your entire page (you wish).

Comment: You're binding .live() functions inside a .live() function. That may not be the cause, but it's definitely not right.

Comment: Except of the question being too localized, it can't be answered without the markup, and knowing what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: You guys all have good comments. Thanks!
I thought my mistake would simply be in "$('[data^=' + boxID + ']').slideUp('3000');" I probably have to reorganize this structure.

Answer (score 0):

On the click event, to hide the one that was clicked, you can use `$(this).hide()` as oppose to naming the class/ID of the element.